# Nightshift keeps turning itself off

Tags: macos, mojave, night-shift

No matter how many times I turn on Nightshift, it keeps turning itself off.

I only ever use the "custom" time range, not the "by timezone" range. Perhaps there is a bug with this setting, instead of location-based timezone?

I currently have it set to `7:09pm to 7:00am`

`10.14.5 (18F203)` but the problem has been happening for most of Mojave, if not all of it.

I haven't reinstalled macOS or made an OS update during this time.  I may have rebooted – but I can't understand why rebooting should disable my preference setting!

Comment: I don't understand the downvote.  Maybe my issue isn't believable?

Comment: I've been having the same problem since the feature first came out. It's been 1+ years, still no fix.

Comment: @NewAlexandria What Time range do you use?

Comment: Hey @NewAlexandria ! You should at least ping me that you've updated the post. I see two reasons 1. You unchecking the manual setting which favours night shift if checked. 2. Colors are less warm. Also at what time of the day do you observe that it is turned off?

Comment: Happens to me a lot. I found this reported elsewhere. Seems bug-like. I never had these issues with the "f.lux" app and I'm tired of fiddling with settings, so I'm just going back to that app.